# What if a being-waited thread detaches itself?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

```
#include <pthread.h>

void thread_routine(void*)
{
    sleep(5);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    sleep(5);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, 0, thread_routine, 0);
    pthread_join(t);
}
```

Will `pthread_join(t);` return immediately after `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` succeed?

Comment: My guess, the same as if the thread was detached before the call to `pthread_join`: UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is undefined, and thus obviously to be avoided at all costs.

(As far as I can tell the behavior is *implicitly* undefined.  There are several kindred instances of [*explicitly* undefined behavior in the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_02), but this exact scenario is not mentioned.)

For the curious, on an NPTL Linux system near me, both the `pthread_detach()` and the `pthread_join()` return 0, and, moreover, the latter blocks and successfully gets the value returned by the thread.  On an OS X system near me, by contrast, the `pthread_detach()` succeeds, and the `pthread_join()` immediately fails with ESRCH.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is buggy. By the time you call `pthread_join`, the thread may already have terminated. Since it's detached, the `pthread_t` is not longer valid. So your code may pass an invalid `pthread_t` to `pthread_join`, which can cause unpredictable behavior.

To avoid these kinds of problems one specific thing should control the lifetime of a thread. That can be the thread itself, if it's detached, in which case no thread should try to join it. It can also be the thread that joins it, in which case the thread should not be detached.

Comment: This is all true and great guidance, but is off point.  The OP's question is, what happens if a thread that is the target of a join detaches itself during the join?  It's true that `sleep()` is the fool's gold of synchronization, and also that the OP's `thread_routine` _could_ terminate its 10 second life before the `main` thread got around to calling join.  In practice, however, the post is a good contrivance of just what @xmllmx is asking and you don't answer that directly.

Comment: I'd say that in that case it boils down to which functions can be called concurrently on a pthread_t.

Comment: @pilcrow The answer is the same regardless of how you create the race. The behavior is unpredictable because you can't guarantee the `pthread_t` remains valid.

Comment: I can't tell if we're saying the same thing.  :)  Let me rephrase:  the question is what happens when a valid/viable `pthread_t` is the target of a join and then _while the join is in progress_ also the target of a `detach`.  The `pthread_t` is valid for each caller at the time of the call.

Comment: @pilcrow Right, and my answer is that there will always be a race condition, so it will always be unpredictable. Try to write such code without a race condition *you cannot do it*. (Think about it, how could you ever know the join was in progress as opposed to waiting to start?)

Comment: Right, but the question isn't how do I avoid this race, the question is, what is the system behavior when the race leads to outcome A as opposed to outcome B?  We can know that joining thread is blocking in its call, either with confidence because of the `sleep` or with certainty via tracing...

Comment: @pilcrow I don't agree. I see no evidence that the OP understood that this was necessarily UB and that any outcome was possible according to the standard, and such an understanding would have been required for the question to mean what you say.