# Can I call pthread_join on a pthread_detached thread?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have 16 threads that spawned from one parent thread. I'm waiting for the children to finish execution by calling pthread_join in the parent. However, afterwards in each of the children threads I call pthread_detach. I'm wondering if the parent will still wait for the children to finish executing. In the man page it says for pthread_detach: "When a detached thread terminates, its resources are
       automatically released back to the system without the need for
       another thread to join with the terminated thread."

Comment: Kindred question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27262926/132382

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I call pthread_join on a pthread_detached thread?

No.

> I'm wondering if the parent will still wait for the children to finish executing.

It's undefined behaviour.

[`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) says:

> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the thread argument to `pthread_join()` does not refer to a joinable thread.

A detached thread is not joinable.

If a child thread changes itself to detached while another thread is trying to join it, you are now joining a non-joinable thread.

You should call either `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` *at most once* for each thread. Do not call both for the same thread.

Comment: Do you know why there is no method to query state of thread: detached or joinable. We can use pthread_attr_getdetachstate but this does not cover the case where user detach thread via pthread_detach method. Thanks!

Comment: If your program is just wildly creating threads with no knowledge of their state then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that does not answer the question.

Comment: You asked why there is no function to do it, and I said it's not needed in properly-written programs. That answers the question. The pthreads programming model expects such a function to be unnecessary.